# Variable as the property name in a JavaScript object literal?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add a property to a Javascript Object using a variable as the name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695050/how-do-i-add-a-property-to-a-javascript-object-using-a-variable-as-the-name)
>   [Use variable for property name in JavaScript literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638659/use-variable-for-property-name-in-javascript-literal)

Is it possible to add a variable as the property name of an object in JavaScript, like this:

```
var myVar = "name";
var myObject = {
    {myVar}: "value"
};
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567278/use-javascript-variable-in-object-name?rq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855473/javascript-expression-to-define-objects-property-name?rq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4694652/javascript-creating-object-and-assigning-variable-for-property-name?rq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9367572/javascript-object-literal-keys , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638659/javascript-property-and-object?rq=1

Comment: Well, SO most likely suggested one of them while writing the question...

Comment: -1 I gave a downvote because there is an *overwhelming* number of similar questions. (The term "literal" might also be good in a search, as it will reveal that this can't be done in a literal.)

Comment: I was asking about the possibility of including the variable directly in the object writing, like my example, a thing that is not referenced in the threads mentioned. I will presume that this is not possible then.

Comment: None of those other questions address the issue of using the value of a variable as a property name within an object literal.

Answer (score 220):

### Edit

With ES6, this is now possible using a [ComputedPropertyName](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-initializer), which manifests in the form of the following syntax:

```
var myVar = "name";
var myObject = {
    [myVar]: "value"
};
```

---

You can use the `[]` syntax to use an *expression* as the property name (compared to the `.prop` and `prop: value` syntaxes where they are always treated as strings):

```
var myObject = {};
var myVar = "name";
myObject[myVar] = "value";
```

There is no way to use that inside an object literal, though. You have to create the object first and then assign each property separately.

Comment: +1 for words. Words are always nice.

Comment: +1 for explicitly mentioning that there is no way to do this within an object literal.  (That's the reason we're all here, isn't it?)

Comment: And more points for the update so latecomers gets to know that it has since become possible!

Answer (score 12):

Like this?

```
var myVar = "name";
var myObject = {};

myObject[myVar] = "value";
```

Answer (score 10):

Yes, but not directly.

```
var myVar = "name";
var object = {};
object[myVar] = "value";
```

Comment: If you want a one-liner: `var object = Object.defineProperty( {}, myVar, { value: "value" } );`

Comment: @IsaacKleinman Then it can't be iterated, overwritten, or deleted.

Comment: @Scimonster: you can: 
`var object = Object.defineProperty( {}, myVar, { value: "value", enumerable: true, writable: true, configurable: true } );` still one line. ;)

Comment: @IsaacKleinman Fair enough, but by then it's almost longer than this solution. BTW you're missing a comma before `enumerable`.

Comment: I've been looking for how to do that middle step for hours. Thank you.