# Jquery Ajax issue,not taking options value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Hello People here is my code below...

```
$.fn.myajax = function (options) {

    var defaults = {
        my_event: "",
        my_url: "",
        my_data: "",
    }
    var o = {};
    var mydata = options.my_data;
    $.extend(o, defaults, options);

    return this.each(function () {
        $(this).bind(options.my_event, function (event) {

            $.ajax({
                url: options.my_url,
                global: false,
                type: "GET",
                data: ({
                    mydata: $('#' + this.id).val()
                }),
                cache: false,
                success: function (html) {
                    console.log('Done Baby :)');
                }
            });
        });
    });
};
```

In Ajax Data Field `data: ({mydata:$('#'+this.id).val()}),` it is passing 'mydata' as get variable not `options.my_data` I also tried ,
data: ({options.my_data:$('#'+this.id).val()}),`but got some error so had to stored in variable but not working...it is passing an url something like this`http://my_domain.com/serverpage?mydata=friend`But iam expecting`http://my_domain.com/serverpage?name=friend`where`name`is in`options.my_data; I have already tried `data: {'mydata':$('#' + this.id).val()}` and also checked this question [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11043026/variable-as-the-property-name-in-a-javascript-object-literal)

But did not solve my problem...

Comment: You can just do `mydata: this.value` right?

Comment: No if i check in console. .. it is passing `mydata` in Url not the `Value inside mydata`...let me explain more in question.. wait...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to build the data array separately, because it's not something you can do with array literals:

```
var to_send = {};
to_send[options.my_data] = $(this).val();

...
$.ajax({
    ...
    data: to_send
    ...
});
```

Comment: @Friend Okay, think I got your problem now :)

Comment: It makes More sense :) You rock Buddy.. Its working fine now :)...Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I got your question, but it seems you'd like to get the string inside your 'mydata' variable, is that right?

For example, if mydata is a string "smallball", you'd like to have:

```
 data: ({
      smallball: $('#' + this.id).val()
 }),
```

EDIT, correct answer:

```
 var dataAux = {};
 dataAux[mydata] = $('#' + this.id).val();
```

Inside your jQuery:

```
 data: dataAux;
```

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/KusmV/

Comment: after using `eval` i see this error in console.. `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ( `