# Get value from paragraph tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to get value from paragraph tag

```
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="<fmt:message key="label.modal.confirmation" />">
</div>
<div style="display:none" id="parent">
<p class="yes"><fmt:message key="button.modal_ok" /></p>
<p id="no"><fmt:message key="button.modal_no" /></p>
</div>
```

in my javascript function

```
$(function() {
var butok = $('#parent').children('p.yes').text();
$( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  resizable: false,
  height:140,
  modal: true,
  buttons: {
      butok : function() {
      window.location.href = partsArray[0];
      $(this).dialog( "close" );
    },
    butno: function() {
        location.reload();
      $( this ).dialog( "close" );
    }
  }
});
});
```

How can i get it? .text() and .html() does not work

Comment: You're storing the text in a `butok` variable, but you're never using it... ? If you do `alert(butok);` right after defining it, it should alert the right value.

Comment: @blex, agreed. Yeah, is there more code to this? Because one of the problems could be that you do not have a closing `div` tag. And jQuery cannot find the `.children()` of an unclosed tag?

Comment: i am newbie in it, just want get parameters from <p> tag and put it to the button, if you give me some code it will be really helpfull. Thank you anyway !

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/a6wfknx4/ - html() is working actually...

Comment: @blex,  with alert(butok) it works, but with button - no

Comment: Did you make sure that you have linked your code to jQuery? By including: `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>`?

Comment: @King, yes, I am sure

Comment: Please create a demo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly use `butok` as you did, because the button text will be `"butok"`, not the value of the variable. To be able to do that, you need to add the property separately. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11043026/variable-as-the-property-name-in-a-javascript-object-literal).

**Fixed code**

```
var butok = $('#parent').children('p.yes').text(),
    butno = $('#parent').children('p#no').text();

// Define an empty Object
var myButtonsObject = {};

// Add properties to it using the [ bracket ] notation
myButtonsObject[ butok ] = function() {
    window.location.href = partsArray[0];
    $(this).dialog("close");
};

myButtonsObject[ butno ] = function() {
    location.reload();
    $(this).dialog("close");
};


$("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: false,
    height: 140,
    modal: true,
    buttons: myButtonsObject  // Use it
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$(function() {

  var butok = $('#parent').children('p.yes').text(),
    butno = $('#parent').children('p#no').text();

  // Define an empty Object
  var myButtonsObject = {};

  // Add properties to it using the [ bracket ] notation
  myButtonsObject[butok] = function() {
    window.location.href = partsArray[0];
    $(this).dialog("close");
  };

  myButtonsObject[butno] = function() {
    location.reload();
    $(this).dialog("close");
  };


  $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    resizable: false,
    height: 140,
    modal: true,
    buttons: myButtonsObject // Use it
  });

});
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Modal title"></div>
<div style="display:none" id="parent">
  <p class="yes">Yeeeees</p>
  <p id="no">Nooooo</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Dont know what i am doing wrong, but it still is not working

Comment: @Ilya Open your JavaScript console (F12, and select the `console` tab). Do you see any errors?

Comment: yes. Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'open'

Comment: @Ilya Haha, you found what was wrong? Good job, and you're welcome! I added a demo under my answer, it should work.

Comment: Yes, i just lost the bracket. I saw, you really help me, thank you one more time!