# How to setState with name dynamically?

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

I'm trying to validate each input field. Assuming I have 5 input fields, how do I set 'error' state for each input field. For example, this.setState({error['roleShortName'] : true }), This won't work and in input, invalid={this.state.error["roleShortName"]}.

```
<FormGroup row>
      <Label for="roleshortname" sm={4}>roleshortname</Label>
            <Col sm={8}>
                 <Input invalid={this.state.error}
                      autoComplete='off'
                      onChange={this.handleChange}
                      type="text"
                      value={this.state.roleShortName}
                      name="roleShortName"
                      />
             </Col>
</FormGroup>

<FormGroup row>
     <Label for="rolefullname" sm={4}>rolefullname</Label>
            <Col sm={8}>
                  <Input invalid={this.state.error}
                   autoComplete='off'
                   onChange={this.handleChange}
                   type="text"
                   value={this.state.roleName}
                   name="roleName"
              </Col>
</FormGroup>
<Button onClick={() => this.handleAddConfirm()}
```

```
handleAddConfirm() {

        if (!this.state.roleShortName) {
            this.setState({ error: true })
            return
        }
        else if (!this.state.roleName) {
            this.setState({error: true})
            return
        }
```

Comment: `this.setState({error['roleShortName'] : true })` is this code not working for you ?

Comment: No it's not working. it's saying  ' : ' expected or I'm doing it wrong?  :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variable as the property name in a JavaScript object literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11043026/variable-as-the-property-name-in-a-javascript-object-literal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.setState({error['roleShortName']: true})` won't work. If you want the key to be dynamic, here's how it should look like:

`this.setState({[error['roleShortName']]: true})`

Notice the `[]` surrounding the key name.

**Edit**: I think you're looking for a dictionary to hold an error for each input:

```js
handleAddConfirm() {
        var newErrors = {...this.state.errors}
        if (!this.state.roleShortName) {
            newErrors["roleShortName"] = true
        }
        else if (!this.state.roleName) {
            newErrors["roleName"] = true
        }
        this.setState({ errors: newErrors })
        return
}
```

In your constructor, you should have

```js
this.state = {errors: {}}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to this stuff, I'm getting error is undefined here, where and how do I define it?

Comment: I don't think what you're looking for is dynamic key names. I think you want a dictionary to hold your errors for each input. See me updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something general provided your input field has a name attribute.

You pick up the name from preferably blur `event` and set the value of error to it.

```
[e.target.name] = [e.target.value]
```

In your case, in the error object just set the name property and value like this

```
// check for error on `e.target.name` field and if true

this.setState({ error[e.target.name]: true } )
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialise an object in constructor which will hold error state of each input fields.

```
constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.state = {
   errorFields: {}
 }
}

<Input invalid={this.state.errorFields.roleShortName}
       autoComplete='off'
       onChange={this.handleChange}
       type="text"
       value={this.state.roleShortName}
       name="roleShortName"
/>
```

```
    handleChange(e) {
      const { name, value } = e.target;
      let errorFields = this.state.errorFields;
      errorFields[name] = false;
      if (!value) {
        errorFields[name] = true;    
      }
      this.setState({
       errorFields,
       [name]: value
      });
    }
```

Then in handleAddConfirm function.

```
handleAddConfirm(e) {
   let indexOfInvalidState Object.values(this.state.errorFields).indexOf(true);
   if (indexOfInvalidState > -1) {
      return false;
   }
}
```