# evaluate variable as part of JSON query

Tags: javascript, json

I've got this:

```
var JSON = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name1": "Seymore Butts",
        "name2": "Jane Doe",
        "name3": "John Smith",
        "name4": "Mike Hawk"
    }];
for (i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    var index = "name" + i;
    window.console.log(JSON[0].index);
}
```

and of course it's getting undefined because it's looking for

```
JSON[0].index
```

instead of

```
JSON[0].name1
```

Any way to force it to evaluate the index var instead of just reading "index"?

Comment: For future reference, you have an array of *javascript objects*, not *JSON* (which is always, by definition, a string)

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript object: access variable property by name as string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255472/javascript-object-access-variable-property-by-name-as-string), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153969/create-object-using-variables-for-property-name, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241875/how-to-create-object-property-from-variable-value-in-javascript, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4694652/javascript-creating-object-and-using-variable-for-property-name, etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup, just change your syntax to:

```
window.console.log(JSON[0][index]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
for (i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    var index = "name" + i;
    window.console.log(JSON[0][index]);
}
```

The difference between `.` and `[]` here is that `object.sub_field` will try to access field named `sub_field`, while `object[sub_field]` will try to access field named by "whatever is in variable `sub_field`".